# Material Design how to use the Sibling transitions in web (Horizontal scroll effect in tab bar)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Good morning people
I'm trying to create a Material design scroll transition effect (Sibling transitions) as image and link below:

[image: 1]

[text](https://m2.material.io/design/navigation/navigation-transitions.html#peer-transitions)

I already managed to replicate the tabs but the scroll effect does not occur when a tab is changed, can anyone help? Thank you very much in advance

`

```
<div class="mdc-tab-bar" role="tablist">
  <div class="mdc-tab-scroller">
    <div class="mdc-tab-scroller__scroll-area">
      <div class="mdc-tab-scroller__scroll-content">
        <button class="mdc-tab mdc-tab--active" role="tab" aria-selected="true" tabindex="0">
          <span class="mdc-tab__content">
            <span class="mdc-tab__text-label">One</span>
          </span>
          <span class="mdc-tab-indicator mdc-tab-indicator--active">
            <span class="mdc-tab-indicator__content mdc-tab-indicator__content--underline"></span>
          </span>
          <span class="mdc-tab__ripple"></span>
        </button>
        <button class="mdc-tab mdc-tab" role="tab" aria-selected="true" tabindex="0">
          <span class="mdc-tab__content">
            <span class="mdc-tab__text-label">Two</span>
          </span>
          <span class="mdc-tab-indicator mdc-tab-indicator">
            <span class="mdc-tab-indicator__content mdc-tab-indicator__content--underline"></span>
          </span>
          <span class="mdc-tab__ripple"></span>
        </button>
        <button class="mdc-tab mdc-tab" role="tab" aria-selected="true" tabindex="0">
          <span class="mdc-tab__content">
            <span class="mdc-tab__text-label">Three</span>
          </span>
          <span class="mdc-tab-indicator mdc-tab-indicator">
            <span class="mdc-tab-indicator__content mdc-tab-indicator__content--underline"></span>
          </span>
          <span class="mdc-tab__ripple"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="content content--active">
  <p>Content one</p></div>
<div class="content">
  <p>Content two</p>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <p>Content three</p>
</div>
```

`

`

```
.content {
  display: none;
}

.content--active {
  display: block;
}
```

`

codepen: [text](https://codepen.io/arunachu/pen/xxxMMOM)

I already managed to replicate the tabs but the scroll effect does not occur when a tab is changed,

Answer (score 0):

quite simble but complex.
a big container that has all elements inside him with a flex column

CSS

```
   .main{
      display: felx;
      flex-direction: column;
      position : absolute;
      top : 0;
      left : calc((100% / 2) - ((100% / 3)/2)); /* replace 3 with number of sections required */
}

   section{
      height : 90%; /* leaving 10% for the nav bar */
      width : 100vw;
      /* all must be the same size and if there is a gap, the gap must be subtracted using this method calc((100% / 2) - ((((100% - <gap size * number of gapes) / number of sections))/2)) */
}
```

HTML

```
<main>
   <section id="sec--1" onclick="moveSection(this)"></section>
   <section id="sec--2" onclick="moveSection(this)"></section>
   <section id="sec--3" onclick="moveSection(this)"></section>
</main>
```

now every thing is ready for javascript

any element that is in active mode shall be in the middle
so we are going to change the parmeter in the calc() function in css and that is it, using the id and using str.slice(); method in javascript you can slice and concatenate it to int so you can use the method below:

```
function moveSection(e){
  let active panel = e.id.slice(-1);
  let main = document.getElementsByTagName('main')[0]);
  // change main styling to the right equation
}
```

the soloution logic is right but DO NOT copy my code, not going to work, it is missing alot of optimizations. if you still need further more help, I am available.

Comment: Thank you for your help

Does material design already make this code available open source? I say this because I got the tabs example in an open source way, I didn't want to create this script from scratch

Comment: oh... so not all are, but there is what I use https://m3.material.io/

Comment: If you found my answer helpful and satisfies your question, may you mark it as the Correct answer please  ?